# Tensorflow tf.data to operate on image based on contents of another file

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have 3 files img0_x.jpg img0_y.jpg img0_minmax.txt

img0_minmax.txt has 4 lines of text with 4 values like this:

```
xmin: -3.64646
xmax: 2.7953
ymin: -2.85746
ymax: 3.57254
```

I want to have a tf.data pipeline that will load the two jpg files and the txt file and scale the values of the _x.jpg based on xmin and xmax, and the _y.jpg based on ymin and ymax.

How can I do it? Is py_func the only way?

For loading the 3 files:

```
def _read_flows(x_img, y_img, minmax):
    x_img_str = tf.read_file(x_img)
    x_img_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(x_img_str, channels=1)
    y_img_str = tf.read_file(y_img)
    y_img_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(y_img_str, channels=1)
    return x_img_decoded, y_img_decoded, minmax
```